# How to calculate ± deviation for precision and recall?

Tags: precision-recall, precision, average-precision, precision-matrix

I found a precision and recall report table like as below

> Precision           Recall
>
> .470±.009         .934±.013
>
> .239±.010          .610±.013

I need the guidelines for ±.009 and ±.013 etc. What ± means and how to calculate it? Guide me for my situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably obtained with bootstrapping, can you share where you saw it?

Comment: Please go through the link : https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Mean-Standard-Deviation-of-Precision-and-Recall-of-compared-methods-on-Spectralis-OCT_tbl2_320372468

Comment: Guide me for my situation.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

In the paper, Page 4, it says:

> ...The detected cysts were then classified with texture descriptors based on Gray Level Co-occurrence Matrix (GLCM) and Gabor filters and by using classifiers such as Naive-Bayes (NB), Support Vector Machine (SVM) or Random Forest (RF) with **10-fold cross validation**. The comparative evaluation in [21] indicates that GLCM + SVM and Gabor + SVM have segmentation accuracies of 0.8293 and 0.8244, respectively...

They do not specifically talk about it anywhere else in the paper, but the precision/recall mean/std values in the table you've shown were most probably calculated via these validation folds, i.e. an array of 10 precision values, and mean/std of them for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable reply. I will check with sample data and let you know. Thanks